# How can maximum protection for a clone stored in a demiplane be achieved?

Tags: dnd-5e, planes, character-death

I'm looking to create a way for an NPC of mine to become immortal, without becoming undead or requiring the aid of an ally who could die or betray the NPC. The NPC's "class" is not yet final (as in: I could make the NPC a wizard as well as a warlock or a bard. I'm aware I'm not limited to class restrictions, but wizards are different from clerics lore-wise as well, so I'd like to avoid spell mix-ups there).

The *[Clone](https://www.dnd-spells.com/spell/clone)* spell, an 8th-level wizard spell, allows the creation of an inanimate clone of a chosen creature. Once it's matured, the original creatures' soul can enter the clone if the original creature dies, therefore allowing the creature to "survive" death.
Since this might be the cloned creature's last chance to avoid dying (sort of), it'll obviously want to protect this body, and not just put it in some random basement.

I'm thinking about using *[Demiplane](https://www.dnd-spells.com/spell/demiplane)* to protect the body, with the added benefit of protecting a few items that are important to the NPC (this desire might or might not be related to chaotic neutral party members).
The spell basically creates access to a small, cubic 30x30x30 foot room that forms its own, well, demiplane. The plane can be reached using the *[Demiplane](https://www.dnd-spells.com/spell/demiplane)* spell itself, or by using other means of traveling between planes (such as *[Plane Shift](https://www.dnd-spells.com/spell/plane-shift)* or *[Gate](https://www.dnd-spells.com/spell/gate)*. See also PHB, p. 302). Leaving the plane after the casting of *[Demiplane](https://www.dnd-spells.com/spell/demiplane)* used to get there has ended requires one of the latter means.

**Which spells, class features, magic items etc. are available to achieve maximum protection for a demiplane?**

Of course, *[Wish](https://www.dnd-spells.com/spell/wish)* can basically trump pretty much anything else you could do, but I'm not looking for "I wish that anyone but me who enters this plane against my will dies" solutions, since that might block you from ever using *[Wish](https://www.dnd-spells.com/spell/wish)* again.

Related question: [Does Clone spell makes someone effectively immortal?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/50541/does-clone-spell-makes-someone-effectively-immortal)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to use spells to protect your clone's body. I'm not aware of any class features that could aid this task, aside from maybe a cleric's *Divine Intervention*.

The following spells are suitable:

#### Wizard:

- *[Glyph of Warding](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/glyph-of-warding)*. Can be detonated or cast a spell when a trigger occurs.
- *[Symbol](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/symbol)*: can cause harmful effects when triggered.
- *[Sequester](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/sequester)* (protect your clone from divination spells; might be impossible to cast, since you have to touch the body, which is now inside a sealed container that may not be disturbed)
- *[Guards and Wards](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/guards-and-wards)*. Has to be cast every day for 1 year.
- *[Mordenkainen's Private Sanctum](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/private-sanctum)*. Has to be cast every day for a year to be permanent. You might want to leave a spot in your demiplane so that you can get out - the spell blocks planar travel. On the other hand, that might be to your advantage - if your soul enters your clone, it's not considered planar travel, and you can just end the effect using an action once you've returned to your body.
- *[Finger of Death](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/finger-of-death)*. Creates zombies permanently under your control, though it requires you to kill someone with the spell first. Might be a little inconvenient depending on your alignment.
- *[Simulacrum](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/simulacrum)*: Create a friendly copy of a creature that can guard your clone. Unless you create a simulacrum of a creature that doesn't require food and water, you'll have to provide these things to the simulacrum (maybe by using *Sequester*?). Note that you can only create simulacrums of beasts or humanoids, not constructs or undead, which would probably not require food/water.
- *[Programmed Illusion](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/programmed-illusion)* (this is more of utility-protection-spell - it won't actually harm anyone directly, but you could, for example, make it trigger when intruders cross a dangerous trap, so they're spooked and trip. Or, if you're feeling friendly, use it to warn intruders to back off. Though that kind of interferes with "maximum security")
- *[Create Homunculus](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/create-homunculus)* (pretty weak stats, but better than nothing)
- *[Planar Binding](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/planar-binding)* (as high-level as possible) + conjuration spell, such as *[Conjure Elemental](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/conjure-elemental)*. You'll have to re-cast this every once in a while, though - even with a 9th-level slot, it only lasts 1 year and 1 day. Note that this can be dangerous to cast - the creature that is to be bound by the spell might succeed on the save or harm you before you finish the casting.
- *[Geas](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/geas)*. Note that this spell might put you at more risk than without it - the target doesn't *have* to abide by its instructions, it just takes damage if it does. Also, if you use anything lower than a 9th-level-slot, it has a limited duration. Could be more useful if combined with *Sequester*.
- *[Arcane Lock](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/arcane-lock)*. "You want to open this lock, intruder? Well, now it's harder!"
- *[Drawmij's Instant Summons](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/instant-summons)*: retrieve the equipment from your corpse. You'd better hurry, though - it doesn't work if someone is holding the piece of equipment.
- *[Magic Mouth](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/magic-mouth)*: Only helpful if you want to read a fancy monologue to intruders.
- *[Major Image](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/major-image)*: Only visual, doesn't deal damage or anything like that. Lasts until dispelled only when used with a 6-th-level or higher slot.
- *[Nystul's Magic Aura](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/arcanists-magic-aura)*: Give fake information when targeted by divination spells (among other things). Only lasts indefinitely when cast on the same target for 30 days in a row.
- *[Wish](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wish)*, to save costs on material components or to cast spells that are not otherwise available for wizards (e.g. *[Hallow](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hallow)*).

#### Bard:

- *[Symbol](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/symbol)*
- *[Guards and Wards](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/guards-and-wards)*
- *[Programmed Illusion](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/programmed-illusion)*
- *[Planar Binding](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/planar-binding)* + conjuration spell
- *[Glyph of Warding](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/glyph-of-warding)*
- *[Magic Mouth](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/magic-mouth)*
- *[Major Image](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/major-image)*
- *[Geas](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/geas)*

#### Cleric:

- *[Symbol](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/symbol)*
- *[Planar Binding](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/planar-binding)* + conjuration spell
- *[Forbiddance](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/forbiddance)*: blocks planar travel and damages one or more of: celestials, elementals, fey, fiends, and undead.
- *[Hallow](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hallow)*
- *[Ceremony](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/ceremony)*: can be used to create one vial of water/casting. If you have **a lot** of time on your hands, you can make use of this to create a layer of holy water in your demiplane. Or just buy the holy water, this spell is just first level and shouldn't be too hard to difficult to acquire.
- *[Geas](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/geas)*
- *[Glyph of Warding](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/glyph-of-warding)*

#### Druid:

- *[Planar Binding](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/planar-binding)* + conjuration spell
- *[Druid Grove](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/druid-grove)*: your DM might or might not consider a demiplane a valid location for this spell.
- *[Geas](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/geas)*

#### Sorcerer:

- *[Major Image](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/major-image)*
- *[Finger of Death](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/finger-of-death)*
- *[Wish](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wish)*, and therefore any other spells of 8th level and lower that are listed here for other classes. Still, it'll be a lot more difficult, since you only get to cast one of these spells per day.

#### Warlock:

- *[Major Image](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/major-image)*
- *[Finger of Death](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/finger-of-death)*

#### Paladin:

- *[Ceremony](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/ceremony)*
- *[Geas](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/geas)*

### Shaping the terrain in your demiplane:

- *[Mold Earth](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/mold-earth)*
- *[Transmute Rock](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/transmute-rock)*: creates muddy, quicksand-like ground.
- *[Fabricate](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/fabricate)*
- *[Create or Destroy Water](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/create-or-destroy-water)*
- *[Plant Growth](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/plant-growth)*
- *[Stone Shape](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/stone-shape)*
- *[Wall of Stone](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wall-of-stone)*: create walls of stone to block things off. Duh.