# Is there any way to become immortal in D&D 5e?

Tags: dnd-5e

I've been thinking of maybe making an immortal character, either from the start, or throughout the campaign, and was wondering if there is any way of making that a reality.

Is there any way of starting with an immortal character? If so, how?

If not, how can my character achieve immortality throughout the campaign if that's possible at all?

Comment: What do you mean by immortal? Does the character have to be immune to death by age and mundane disease, mundane injury, everything including highly specific magic? Does the immortality have to be unconditional or can it be dependent on some action or staying in some location?

Comment: What sort of impact do you want immortality to have on the game? (Being entirely unkillable seems pretty boring in a combat focused system like D&D, having a Highlander-style game with flashbacks to historical events could be interesting, but a typical D&D setting would make that kind of story hard to support and the massive power difference levelling brings would make it a bit odd with that ruleset. You might have something entirely different in mind.)

Comment: To emphasize @Quentin's questions: different "kinds" of immortality lead to different solutions! A *Boon of Immortality* only prevents death from aging, so the character can live forever until killed, while the *Warrior of the Gods* feature of the *Path of the Zealot* allows being resurrected without paying for material components, giving a more Highlander-style "revival". Unless you detail what you expect, an answer would have to try and list all possibilities, and you may still not be satisfied...

Comment: This question might also be helpful for you to look at :)    : https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/144560/how-can-i-make-my-bbeg-immortal-short-of-making-them-a-lich-or-vampire

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a way to be free of the effects of aging (undying) then you can create an [Oath of the Ancients paladin](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/paladin#OathoftheAncients) (PHB 86). Paladins get the Divine Health feature (making them immune to disease) at 3rd level, and Oath of the Ancients paladins get the Undying Sentinel feature at 15th level:

> Starting at 15th level, when you are reduced to 0 hit points and are not killed outright, you can choose to drop to 1 hit point instead. Once you use this ability, you can’t use it again until you finish a long rest.
>
> **Additionally, you suffer none of the drawbacks of old age, and you can’t be aged magically**.

Basically, you'll need to be killed in some way in order to die. It fits well with the idea of the archetype, too.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.